# Compare dates from two different dataframes to calculate fields

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames and I want to use the date in one dataframe to calculate some fields from another data dataframe. Is there a better way to do this besides how I have done this below? In a toy example I have a dataframe of players and their injury datetime, and in another I have their games with then they played. I want to calculate if the player played a game before and after their injury and return a flag stating they did and the name of the game they played. Then I want to put this result back into the first dataframe.

It should look something like this:

df_A

```
    id  texts                   injury_date
0   1   text for person 1       2020-01-01
1   2   text for person 2       2020-02-01
2   1   text for person 1 AGAIN 2021-05-01
3   4   text for person 4       2022-01-01
```

df_B:

```
    id  games       played_on
0   2   soccer      2019-01-01
1   1   football    2020-02-01
2   1   tennis      2021-05-01
```

and want to get:

```
    id  played after injury played before injury    games played after  games played before
0   1   True                False                   [football, tennis]  []
1   2   False               True                    []                  [soccer]
2   1   False               True                    []                  [football, tennis]
3   4   False               False                   []                  []
```

and merging it like this

```
texts                       id  injury_date played after injury played before injury        games played after  games played before
0   text for person 1       1   2020-01-01  True                False                       [football, tennis]  []
1   text for person 1 AGAIN 1   2021-05-01  True                False                       []                  [football, tennis]
2   text for person 2       2   2020-02-01  False               True                        []                  [soccer]
3   text for person 4       4   2022-01-01  False               False                       []                  []
```

Code:

```
df_A = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1,2,1,4], "texts":['text for person 1', 'text for person 2', 'text for person 1 AGAIN', 'text for person 4'], "injury_date": [pd.to_datetime('1/1/2020'),pd.to_datetime('2/1/2020'),pd.to_datetime('5/1/2021'),pd.to_datetime('1/1/2022')]})

df_B = pd.DataFrame({"id": [2,1,1], "games":['soccer', 'football', 'tennis'], 'played_on': [pd.to_datetime('1/1/2019'),pd.to_datetime('2/1/2020'),pd.to_datetime('5/1/2021')]})

def played_injured(x):
    played_after = df_B[(df_B['id'] == x['id']) & (df_B['played_on'] > x['injury_date'])]# respective to the time for the actual row
    played_before = df_B[(df_B['id'] == x['id']) & (df_B['played_on'] <= x['injury_date'])]
    played_after = played_after.groupby('games',as_index=False).first()
    played_before = played_before.groupby('games',as_index=False).first()
    #print(~played_after.empty)
    return pd.Series({"id":x['id'], "played after injury": len(played_after.index) > 0,"played before injury": len(played_before.index) > 0, "games played after":played_after['games'].tolist(), "games played before":played_before['games'].tolist()})


pd.merge(df_A, df_A.apply(played_injured, axis=1), on=["id"]).groupby('texts', as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to why it returns "[football, tennis]" for after for id 1 (again), when this should be games played before.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah It confused me too. If we do only `df_A.apply(played_injured, axis=1)` without merging it gives us the correct answer. I will fix what I want sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I liked your code, and couldn't find anything to make it more efficient.  The problem with the output was that it was merging on "id" only, which meant that the first `id=1` function output was duplicated.  To solve this, instead of merging the output with the original DataFrame, you can return the initial columns too.

```
def played_injured(x):
    print(x)
    played_after = df_B[(df_B['id'] == x['id']) & (df_B['played_on'] > x['injury_date'])]# respective to the time for the actual row
    print(played_after)
    played_before = df_B[(df_B['id'] == x['id']) & (df_B['played_on'] <= x['injury_date'])]
    print(played_before)
    played_after = played_after.groupby('games', as_index=False).first()
    print(played_after)
    played_before = played_before.groupby('games', as_index=False).first()
    print(played_before)
    #print(~played_after.empty)
    return pd.Series({"id": x['id'], "texts": x["texts"], "injury_date": x["injury_date"],
                      "played after injury": len(played_after.index) > 0,
                      "played before injury": len(played_before.index) > 0,
                      "games played after":played_after['games'].tolist(),
                      "games played before":played_before['games'].tolist()})


df_A.apply(played_injured, axis=1).groupby("texts", as_index=False).first()
```